# Sending a value from an HTML select to PHP with JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html

The HTML with the `select` value is:

```
<select id="value_select" onchange="get_value_js()">
<option>Value 1</option>
<option>Value 2</option
</select>
```

The JavaScript code:

```
function get_value_js() {
var the_value = document.getElementById("value_select").value;
}
```

I don't know how to continue the JavaScript to send the value to, for example, `work.php`. In `work.php`, I want to store the value in a PHP variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use AJAX.

```
function get_value_js(){
  var xmlhttp;
  var e = document.getElementById("value_select");
  var the_value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
      //Do whatever with xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","work.php?val="+the_value,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

You can use $_GET['the_value'] to grab the value.

Comment: I used this example.Thank you moiz.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the `<select>` in a `<form>` tag like so:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="work.php">
    <select name="value_select">
        <option value="1">Value 1 text</option>
        <option value="2">Value 2 text</option
    </select>
</form>
```

Please note that i've added `value` attributes to the `<option>` tags & added a name attribute to the `<select>`.
Next, you can submit the form in the following way:

```
function send()
{
    document.getElementById( "myForm" ).submit();
}
```

Next in work.php:

```
<?
    $value_select = $_POST[ "value_select" ];
    echo( $value_select );
?>
```

Comment: The thing is that i don`t want to be in a form, only in a select, but thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

You could either send it as an [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) call if you want to stay on the same page or perform a redirect and pass the value as query string parameter:

```
window.location.href = '/work.php?value=' + encodeURIComponent(the_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax with jQuery

```
function get_value_js() {
   var the_value =$("#value_select option:selected").val(); 
   $.post('work.php?val='+the_value , function(data) {
        //do whatever you want with the result
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the replyes guys. I used the simple Ajax response, i`m also new to Jquery. Thank you again for the replyes